# Can I find which app is making certain DNS requests?

Tags: applications, dns

So I've been using [pihole](http://pi-hole.net/) and my Android 7 phone is making some unexpected requests to DNS for a particular domain. Is there an app or technique I can use to find which app is initiating those request. It seems the [Java level DNS cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835421/java-dns-cache-viewer) won't have that info.

I'd guess one needs to intercept requests to the phones DNS service (*), recording the requested domain and the requesting app; are their hooks in Android to do that?

I don't have root.
Any help appreciated.

(* - yes I know what this acronym means!)

Comment: If you have root, you can install a DNS server like `dnscrypt-proxy` to view/block all DNS requests. It can be combined with `iptables` owner module to find out which requests are made by which app.

Comment: I'll look at getting root but I'm not sure a safe root is available on my device (Honor 5C, NEM-L51 by Huawei). Thanks for the tip, FWIW I've heard OS Monitor app is useful for tracking such things but it doesn't work on Android7 and up.

Comment: With root you could extract all the APKs (plus app private data) from your device unzip them and make a grep over all the data. If you are lucky you will find the DNS name and therefore know the app.

Comment: Nice idea, could extract suspect apps dl-ed from app store, grep through them, might find something.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Net Monitor](https://github.com/SecUSo/privacy-friendly-netmonitor).
It shows network connections of installed apps.